# Dynamics CRM reporting extensions

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm

I would like to install the Reporting Extensions in our CRM 2015 on premises. I am following this procedure: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699807.aspx

They talk about the file SetupSrsDataConnector.exe that is supposed to be in the folder ..\Server\amd64\SrsDataConnector: I don't find this directory in my servers.

Where can I find the file SetupSrsDataConnector.exe? Can I download it somewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setup is located on the Dynamics CRM installation iso.